# The distance from a point on a line to a plane

Tags: vector-spaces

Assume you have a line e and a plane alpha that are not parallel, How do you calculate the coördinates where point Q will be on that line e at a distance d from the plane.

Assuming that both are given in cartesian equations, I can't seem to figure out how to approach this.

Comment: You mean distance $d$ along the line or in 3D space?

Answer (score 0):

Write the equation of the planes parallel to $\alpha$ having a distance $d$ from it. Then find the intersection between the line $e$ and the planes.

For instance
$$\alpha:x+2y+2z=1;\;d=3;\;e=t(1,1,1)$$

distance from $\alpha$ and the two parallel planes must be $3$ therefore
$$\alpha_1:x+2y+2z=h$$
$$d(\alpha,\alpha_1)=\frac{|1+h|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2+2^2}}=\frac{|1+h|}{3}$$
$$\frac{|1+h|}{3}=3\to |1+h|=9\to h_1=8;\;h_2=-10$$
the parallel planes are
$$\alpha_1:x+2y+2z=8;\;\alpha_2:x+2y+2z=-10$$
intersection with the line $e=(t,t,t)$

with $\alpha_1$ plugging the coordinates of the points of the line

$ t+2t+2t=8\to t=\frac{8}{5}$ point is $\left(\frac{8}{5},\frac{8}{5},\frac{8}{5}\right)$

with $\alpha_2$ we get $t+2t+2t=-10\to t=-2$ point is $(-2,-2,-2)$.

Hope this helps